# Reset post data after "security" code screws with it

Tags: php

I've inherited an ancient and complex system that will be replaced in time, but for now I have one major problem with it.

Somewhere in the (encrypted, yay!) initialisation code is code that mucks around with GPC variables, applying things like `addslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` without regard for any kind of context. You know, the kind of thing an absolute nubcake would do. Not something you'd expect from a somewhat expensive piece of PHP software.

Anyway, ranting aside, is there any way to force PHP to re-read the request's POSTdata and repopulate `$_POST` from it? I've tried my <del>`goto`</del> go-to approach of `file_get_contents("php://input");` but that returns blank - presumably the init code reads that, and since in older versions of PHP it could only be read once... yeah, no-go there.

Any ideas?

Comment: I weep in solidarity with your ire.

Comment: Can't you set your own global variable and re-populate from that after initialization?

Comment: Can you copy it into another variable before the encrypted code?

Comment: It would seem that that is indeed the answer. I was able to get some code in before the init code, to "rescue" the postdata before its bastardisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, but you can always create your own immutable copy of the superglobals *before* this initialization code runs to build this feature on your own.

#### Example:

```
class Superglobals
{
    private $globals;

    public static $singleton;

    public function __construct($globals)
    {
        $this->globals = $globals;
    }

    public function getOriginalValues($key)
    {
        return $this->globals[$key];
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        self::$singleton = new self($GLOBALS);
    }
    public static function restore()
    {
        foreach (['_GET','_POST','_COOKIE','_REQUEST','_SERVER','_ENV'] as $key) {
            $GLOBALS[$key] = self::$singleton->getOriginalValues($key);
        }
    }
}

// at the very beginning:
Superglobals::init();

// anywhere later:
Superglobals::restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple test like:

url?test=asd

```
<?php
$_GET['test'] = 'dsa';

print_r($_GET);
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

the output was: Array ( [test] => dsa ) Array ( [test] => asd )

I think you can use $_REQUEST with $_POST also.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is equally corrupted by the "security" code.

Comment: So i cannot think in any other 'easy' way to workaround it than to rewrite the security code, if you don't wanna have too much trouble rewriting it I would suggest creating a validation session like $_SESSION['request_values'], and check it later. I'm sorry that i was not able to help you, i've been searching the web for it, and this website: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/ seems to have a function that may help you, i would give it a try, although I did not test it. Wish your luck.